# Fluid Design Align Read More Links

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-system

Currently, I'm redesigning my website to be fluid. I'm using the one% css grid. However, I've difficulty with horizontally aligning read more links in several columns. The problem is, that if the viewport gets resized, the readmore links appear beneath each other instead beneath the column it belongs too. This is inherent to the html structure. How can I redesign it to accomplish this?

The main problem is that if you put the readmore links inside the product divs, you can't specify a height since resizing the browser window will change the height (due to text wrapping). In this case, how do you align the readmore links.

Screenshots:

[Aligned links](http://screencast.com/t/06t9fTqI)

[Undesired behaviuor](http://screencast.com/t/xgpmuTaVpt)

HTML Structure (only the one% grid css is applicable, simple floats)

```
    <div class="onerow">
        <div class="col4 product">

        <p><img src="http://arevico.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/product-foto.png"></p>
            <h2>Facebook Lightbox</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col4 product ">
        <p><img src="http://arevico.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/easy-fluid-accordion.png"></p>

            <h2>Custom Plugin Design</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col4 product last">
            <p><img src="http://arevico.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Hopetoun_falls1-297x198.jpg"></p>

            <h2>WP Tactical Popup</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="onerow">
            <!-- Readmore links -->
            <div class="col4"><p><a href="">Learn more</a></p></div>
            <div class="col4"><p><a href="">Learn more</a></p></div>
            <div class="col4 last"><p><a href="">Learn more</a></p></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "learn more" should be in the product div. Than it should work as you want.

```
<div class="onerow">
<div class="col4 product">

    <p>
        <img src="http://arevico.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/product-foto.png">
    </p>
    <h2>Facebook Lightbox</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>

    <p>
        <a href="">Learn more</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col4 product ">
    <p>
        <img src="http://arevico.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/easy-fluid-accordion.png">
    </p>

    <h2>Custom Plugin Design</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>

    <p>
        <a href="">Learn more</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col4 product last">
    <p>
        <img src="http://arevico.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Hopetoun_falls1-297x198.jpg">
    </p>

    <h2>WP Tactical Popup</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="">Learn more</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you horizontally align the various learn more links whilst inside those divs? Especially when the height of those elements change when resized